# WCF REST result XML

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, rest, serialization

I have a WCF rest service. It has a method that returns a list of objects. The object type is set as a DataContract and it has DataMembers. Now it works great, I can get my list of objects as an XML via my method. It is great and nice.

My question is: is there any way to get result XML before returning it from the method? So, can I have exactly the same XML in my method as I can get when calling my method via REST?

.net4/vs2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alfonso's answer is *somewhat* right, but you mentioned you're using `DataContract` and `DataMember`. The `XmlSerializer` class is not meant to be used with data contracts. Instead what you're looking for is `DataContractSerializer`. Use of that is very similar, but would look like this instead:

```
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(YourResultType));
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

using(XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringBuilder))
{
    serializer.WriteObject(xmlWriter, someInstanceOfYourResultType);
}

// use stringBuilder.ToString() to get the XML
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use XmlSerializer to save the result to a xml string before returning it.

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(YourResultType));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
ser.Serialize(sw, yourResult);
// Use sb.ToString()
```

Comment: XmlSerializer will not obey the DataContract/DataMember attributes which Tom mentioned he's using, he would need to use a DataContractSerializer for that.